# How do i loop through an ajax response and display it in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm a PHP developer and i'm looking for something like a foreach loop for an ajax response

I have a card design in html and i would like the response of the ajax request make a new card for each object in the ajax response

This is my code for far

ajax:

```
  $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:"http//url_to_api.com/projects/v1" ,
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(mdata){
             var  result =  '';           
              $.each(mdata,  function (index, element) {               
                result +=    + element.project_name ;  
                console.log(element.project_name); // alert the values 
              });           
              $('.cho-card-title').html(result);


         }
   });
```

html that i want my ajax response to populate for each object in the response data

```
<div class="card-row">          
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-img"> 
            //image.of.ajax.responce
            <img src=""> 
        </div>
        <div class="card-title">
           // title.of.ajax.responce
        </div>
        <div class="card-description">
         //    title.of.ajax.description
        </div>             
        <div class="select-card">
            Select
        </div>          
    </div> 
</div>
```

currently the code loops through the response and displays everything in one card how do I get every response in its own card.

Comment: This is not a code writing service. You write the code, we (maybe) try help fix it. And even if this was a code writing service, exactly what do you think we could do? We can't work off pseudocode. You've provided NO details of what's in this ajax response, what its structure/format is, so all we could do is provide the exact same "Stuff goes here" comments you have, and you're no better off than before.

Comment: What are you talking about I showed my code.

Comment: Did you read my Whole Question because i don't think you did. This code works fine my question is how to loop the response into its own card for each object in the ajax response array. I could show my response array of objects but i thought that was kinda standard.

Comment: I'll just throw this out there... have you ever used AngularJS?  Functionality like this is built-in and can make your life easier (see ngRepeat).  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create and append elements inside the `.each` statement.

This is untested, but something like this might work:

```
$.each(mdata,  function (index, element) {          
  var div = $('<div />') // Create the div
             .addClass('cho-card-title') // Add the class name
             .html(element.project_name); // Insert the html
  // Append the new div to whatever your container is
  $('.container').append(div);
});
```

Comment: This puts the project name in the right element but its still displaying  all the response names in the same card

Comment: @Tsea so modify it to fit your needs.

Comment: Well thats my question @KevinB i already had it displaying the response in one card but i cant figure to get it in separate cards like a foreach loop would do

Comment: ... change the structure of the html being generated... In this answer a div with a class was created and html was inserted into it. modify it slightly to produce the structure of html you are looking for.